# C# Entity Framework Linq Where issue

Tags: c#, linq, where-clause, whitespace, trim

There are two linq queries to MySql DbContext:

```
var letter1 = (from l in dbContext.letters_incoming 
    where l.LetterText.Trim() == "simple letter text".Trim() 
    select l).FirstOrDefault();

var letter2 = dbContext.letters_incoming.Where(new Func<ModelLetterIncoming, bool>(l => {
        string name = l.LetterText;
        if (name == "simple letter text")
           return true;
        else return false;
    })).FirstOrDefault();
```

First query returns null, but second returns correct value. Is it may be caused by whitespaces in my Where condition?

Comment: For one thing calling Trim() on "simple letter text" is redundant and can be removed. That is a string literal with no leading or trailing whitespace, which Trim() elimates.

Comment: First linq query is converted to SQL query and executed in database. Second pulls whole `letters_incoming` table into memory and performs filtering there. This might cause the difference (though not sure why exactly). You can check which SQL query is generated using log (like `dbContext.Database.Log = Console.WriteLine`) and check what query is generated and why it fails to find the line. Might be some collation issue (especially if your strings are not in english).

Comment: Dont really see an error, can you verify the problem with exactly this code?

Comment: @RandRandom, the problem is that I can't select any of entities from my dbset filtering by string values

Comment: @Evk, my IQueryable is turning into SQL with parameter named gp1, so I can't check what SQL was generated

Comment: @RH6, I tried to add Trim() because I thougth that problem in whitespaces. Whithout Trim() result is the same, letter1 is null, but letter2 is not null

Comment: @Evk, I tried to search non-cyrillic symbols and it works, but cyrillic text not returning any entites

Comment: Then check how to work with cyrillic characters (or UTF) in mysql. This issue seems to be not related to EF but to mysql. Make sure your query works without EF first (simple select * from letters where name = "your cyrillic string"). I didn't work with mysql for years so cannot give exact reason.

Comment: @Evk, ADO.NET MySqlDataReader with query
SELECT * FROM letters_incoming WHERE letter_text LIKE '%письмо%'
returns anything, but same query in MySql Workbench returns correct row. inserting to myqsl using linq is working fine with cyrillic.

Comment: @Evk, the problem was in MySqlConnectionStringBuilder, I added mySqlConnectionStringBuilder.CharacterSet = "utf8"; and it works

Comment: Great that it's finally resolved. You might self-answer your own question for future reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem was in MySqlConnectionStringBuilder, I added

```
mySqlConnectionStringBuilder.CharacterSet = "utf8";
```

and it works